# Can't modify Content Access in Media Gallery Module

Tags: users, media

I've got the Media Gallery module installed and want to control the access to it using the Content Access module but can't find how to do that. I get an "Access Control" button on all my other regular pages but don't on the Media Gallery pages.

It sounded like there was an issue with permissions with Drupal 7.2 http://drupal.org/node/1147906 but it was fixed in 7.3. I'm running 7.8 right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the admin/structure/types/manage/media_gallery/access settings page on your site and ensure that the *Enable per content node access control settings* checkbox is checked and then save.